# CSS - Wrapper width match the size of an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image placeholder which dynamically gets images that have different width. I should place navigation elements relative to the image. Since I don't know beforehand what width the image will take, I don't how to set the element so that they are always on the same position relative to the image.

This is my html:

```css
    .magazine-hero {
        position: relative;
    
        .magazine-preview-nav {
          background-color: #FFF;
          width: 57px;
          height: 35%;
          position: absolute;
          top: 10%;
          right: 10px;
          text-align: right;
    
          .right-arrow, .left-arrow {
            position: relative;
            height: 50%;
          }
    
          img {
            width: 35px;
            position: relative;
            top: 33%;
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
          <div class="magazine-hero">
            <img id="image" src="/imagecache/cover/{{ $issues->first()->first()->image }}" alt="" />
    
            <div class="magazine-preview-nav">
                <div class="right-arrow" id="forward">
                  <img src="{{ asset('/img/right-arrow-black.svg') }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-arrow" id="back">
                  <img src="{{ asset('/img/left-arrow-black.svg') }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Put some wrapper of constant width. That way you will put arrows to wrapper, not to image.

Comment: Yes, but I need arrows relative to image not the wrapper.

Comment: Than set images to fixed width. Or show arrows only after images are loaded. Like in http://icoachcricket.ecb.co.uk/